# java Hebrew path changed to?

Tags: java, jetbrains-ide

I am using intalliJ and the latest JDK.
My operation system is in English and some of my folders names are in Hebrew.
When I try to build all my project folders path named in Hebrew changed to ???.

there is a way to fix it?.

[image: image of the problem]

Comment: Do not display error messages as image links. Copy the error and format it as a code block.

Comment: Can you place your code into folders with english names?

Answer (score 2):

You have illegal chars. As one that speaks Hebrew too, You need to create a directory that contains your project in English only (for example inside your user directory). Just put all of your projects there or at least make sure that all the files and directories inside this directory will be in **English only**